# Parsing through Nested JSON array Object nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, object

I am trying to parse a JSON object and delete the Key 'id' with in it, I was able to delete the 'id' which appears in the root of the object but unable to traverse with in the nested array objects which also has 'id' key and delete them, Now follows the code block

```
var json = {
"id" : "a28b469b-b4f2-4846-9b5f-9d866f249bbe",
"description" : "Cost of Product",
"periodicity" : "calendar-monthly",
"Vanilla" : [ {
  "id" : "22382c50-f56f-40b7-a308-203da052c5bc",
  "price" : {
    "amount" : 100.000,
    "currency" : "USD"
  },
  "packing" : "RECURRING",
  "billedInAdvance" : true
} ],
"Chocolate" : [ {
  "id" : "44672921-1966-456e-bde2-87ef72f31cab",
  "price" : {
    "amount" : 256.000000,
    "currency" : "USD"
  },
  "packing" : "Box_Usage"
} ],
"Peach" : [ {
  "id" : "e3a600e2-a2ed-4872-8e6d-5d59ec5ca02d",
  "packing" : "Box_Usage",
  "diff" : [ {
    "pricePerUnit" : {
      "amount" : 25.000000,
      "currency" : "USD"
    },
    "fixedPrice" : {
      "amount" : 36.000000,
      "currency" : "USD"
    }
  } ]
} ],
"Strawberry" : [ {
  "id" : "43b4a121-455a-4828-b4bf-1bacda49f9ce",
  "packing" : "Box_Usage",
  "diff" : [ {
    "pricePerUnit" : {
      "amount" : 100.000000,
      "currency" : "USD"
    }
  } ]
} ]
```

}

I am able to delete the 'id' property within an array object by accessing it through the index, But this wont handle dynamic scenarios when the keys with in the JSON grows. Any suggestion would be valuable

Comment: What is the purpose of deleting IDs?

Comment: I am trying to construct a new json out of the above and use it for a post operation elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it recursively: each time you find an array within the object, you loop through it to remove id in each element.

```js
var json = {
"id" : "a28b469b-b4f2-4846-9b5f-9d866f249bbe",
"description" : "Cost of Product",
"periodicity" : "calendar-monthly",
"Vanilla" : [ {
  "id" : "22382c50-f56f-40b7-a308-203da052c5bc",
  "price" : {
    "amount" : 100.000,
    "currency" : "USD"
  },
  "packing" : "RECURRING",
  "billedInAdvance" : true
} ],
"Chocolate" : [ {
  "id" : "44672921-1966-456e-bde2-87ef72f31cab",
  "price" : {
    "amount" : 256.000000,
    "currency" : "USD"
  },
  "packing" : "Box_Usage"
} ],
"Peach" : [ {
  "id" : "e3a600e2-a2ed-4872-8e6d-5d59ec5ca02d",
  "packing" : "Box_Usage",
  "diff" : [ {
    "pricePerUnit" : {
      "amount" : 25.000000,
      "currency" : "USD"
    },
    "fixedPrice" : {
      "amount" : 36.000000,
      "currency" : "USD"
    }
  } ]
} ],
"Strawberry" : [ {
  "id" : "43b4a121-455a-4828-b4bf-1bacda49f9ce",
  "packing" : "Box_Usage",
  "diff" : [ {
    "pricePerUnit" : {
      "amount" : 100.000000,
      "currency" : "USD"
    }
  } ]
} ]
};
function removeId(obj) {
    delete obj.id;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            obj[key].forEach(o => {
                removeId(o);
            });
        }  
    });
}
removeId(json);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, But i would like to know more if you  have the time, what exactly is happening with in this code block                                                      if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            obj[key].forEach(o => {
                removeId(o);
            });
        }

Comment: "delete obj.id" deletes the property id of obj.
Object.keys(obj) returns an array containing the names of all the keys of obj.
forEach loop throug all the key, then Array.isArray checks if the corresponding value is an array. In case it's an array, loop through it (obj[key].forEach()) to remove the property id in each element by calling the same function removeId and so on

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot. I also put the code in the editor and was going over, Thanks a ton.